# How do I find out I have a high cpu activity on my macbook air, before my battery is used up?

Tags: battery, cpu-usage, macbook-air

I have a Macbook Air.  Occasionally the battery runs down very quickly and it's caused by a high cpu process.  My problem is I don't know this is happening - there's no loud fan noise, just a quicker than normal drain on my batter - and I'd like to catch it quickly before my battery is all gone.  Is there some app I can use to monitor for high cpu usage that will give me an early morning?

Comment: There are numerious applications that will display the CPU loan on your system including tools included with OS X.  What tools have you tried that didn't work out?

Comment: I use activity monitor. I can find apps which tell me the current cpu usage.  I just can't find anything that gives me a warning of prolonged high usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found CPU LEd, a free app, on the app store, with lots of good reviews. It puts a little green, amber, red icon on my menu bar showing CPU load. If it goes RED I think I will notice it.

Answer (score 2):

Application ► Utilities ► **Activity Monitor**

*or*

Terminal ► **top** or **ps**

---

The command *top* will generally show you the information given in the Activity Monitor ordered by the processes using the most resources (like CPU-Time). For more information on the top and ps commands prepend "man" **eg; man top**.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal window and type "top" this will give you several stats including usage.  From a graphical standpoint you can use [iStat](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) which will tell you this and a whole lot more, and may be worth the $16 if you also want to monitor things like temp, memory usage, network throughput, etc.

Comment: Thanks.  When I went looking for iStat I found CPU LEd, a free app, on the app store, with lots of good reviews.  It puts a little green, amber, red icon on my menu bar showing CPU load.  If it goes RED I think I will notice it.